# Como fazer agrupamentos e contar linhas em uma base de dados no R?

Tags: r

Utilizando esta base de dados: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10eODosCJsh4fVAMY-anP-jYeWZk63L-v/view?usp=sharing, preciso calcular a média de mulheres grávidas nos 6 municípios com mais cadastros (usar a variável CODMUNRES para quantificar as mulheres cadastradas) agrupadas pelas idades:

< 16 anos

> = 16 anos e <= 18 anos

> = 19 anos <= 23 anos

> = 24 anos < 30 anos

> = 31 anos < 36

> = 37 anos

Siglas dos dados:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/13CeeOnQ1SRK-rK1XvFP_XBlLipstAzrX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro calculam-se os totais de mulheres grávidas por `CODMUNRES` e por escalão etário.

```
idades <- c(0, 16, 18, 23, 30, 36, Inf)
labels <- c("<16", "17-18", "19-23", "24-30", "31-36", ">36")

tbl <- table(dados$CODMUNRES)
top6 <- head(sort(tbl, decreasing = TRUE), n = 6)
i_top6 <- which(dados$CODMUNRES %in% names(top6))

IDADE <- cut(dados[i_top6, "IDADEMAE"], breaks = idades, labels = labels)
agg <- aggregate(GRAVIDEZ ~ CODMUNRES + IDADE, dados[i_top6, ], length)

head(agg)
#  CODMUNRES IDADE GRAVIDEZ
#1    210140   <16       91
#2    210300   <16      159
#3    210530   <16      166
#4    211120   <16      121
#5    211130   <16      354
#6    211220   <16      164
```

Agora a média de gravidezes por idade nesses 6 códigos.

```
aggregate(GRAVIDEZ ~ IDADE, agg, mean)
#  IDADE  GRAVIDEZ
#1   <16  175.8333
#2 17-18  295.1667
#3 19-23 1044.1667
#4 24-30 1363.8333
#5 31-36  851.5000
#6   >36  319.0000
```

Comment: Obrigado!! ajudou muito!!!